# js regex - allow letters, number and a dash, but not one dash or more on its own

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex that allows letters, number and a dash, which is `([a-z0-9\-]+)`, but I don't want one or more dashes on its own without a letter(s) or a number(s)

Is it possible?

--- Invalid
- Invalid
3e-qw Valid
-3- Valid
-a- Valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following pattern:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-]*(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9-]*
```

https://regex101.com/r/E1yHVY/17

Comment: new to regex, @RomanPerekhrest what if I want to allow space(s) as well in addition to letters, number and dashes

Comment: @bootsa, space will act as a word/item separator in that case, so it can't be properly applied to the condition *one or more dashes on its own*

Answer (score 2):

By use of a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
/^-*\b[a-z\d-]*$/i
```

[demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3ppan1/5/tests)

---

Or requiring one letter/digit:

```
/^-*[a-z\d][a-z\d-]*$/i
```

[demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3ppan1/4/tests)

---

Or use of a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to prevent matching strings only consisting of dashes:

```
/^(?!-+$)[a-z\d-]+$/i
```

[demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3ppan1/2/tests)